# Open Pdf in a new tab using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf-generation

I have my MVC4 Actionresult return a MemoryStream

```
MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + outputFilename + ".pdf");
            return File(memory, "application/pdf");
```

And the Jquery

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Report/Pdf/',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (result) { alert("Done!");}
        });
```

How Do I open a new window/tab and display the PDF file oon the Success function of the AJAX?

Comment: Why do you need to use Ajax for this? Why not just use a link, `location.href = "xyz"` or a `window.open()`?

Comment: Indeed, I believe you want [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open) or an `<iframe>` if you want it embedded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a link, with or without `target=blank` (the former will allow the user to control themselves where they want to open it).

```
 <a href="/Report/pdf">
```

then there's `window.open` but to my knowledge, you can't directly target a new tab with that.

Comment: -Is there a way to convert the Memory stream to a image?

Comment: @Gokul on browser side? Hardly. I think you'll need a server-side solution for that

Comment: Okay.. Saved the Image on Server side and called it in the HTML.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Nips I see no reason why it shouldn't.